# Is there a way to remove reference, cv qualifiers, and pointerness of a type to make it plain?

Tags: c++, type-traits, c++-concepts

Take the following code:

```
struct Foo {}

template<typename T>
void passFoo(T t) {}
```

I would want the domain of `passFoo` to be restricted to `Foo` objects, but I don't mind if they are references, pointers, or cv qualified. Is it possible to somehow remove all those aspects of a type to get down to the "plain" type, when using a concept? For instance:

```
template<typename T>
concept Foo_C = std::is_same_v<Foo, plainify<T>>;

template<Foo_C Foo_c>
void passFoo(Foo_c foo) {}
```

In that hypothetical code, `passFoo` could accept only `Foo`, `Foo&`, `Foo*`, `const Foo`, etc. Is there any actual way to do this?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `std::remove_cv_t` and friends?

Comment: @StephenNewell no, but I was wondering there was maybe an all in one way of doing this

Comment: What about references to the pointer? What about pointer-to-`const`? What about `const` pointer, etc.? In any case you just need to apply `std::remove_cvref_t` and `std::remove_pointer_t` in some chain matching your exact expectation. But such a constraint is not really practically useful. A function must behave very differently when taking an argument by-value, by-reference or by-pointer. Unifying them doesn't really work. And template argument deduction will never deduce a reference or `const` for `T` anyway.

Comment: What about `Foo**`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combination of `std::remove_cvref_t` and `std::remove_pointer_t` would work:

```
template<typename T>
concept Foo_C = std::is_same_v<Foo, std::remove_cvref_t<std::remove_pointer_t<T>>>;
```